# Notice: Undefined index: roles in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, orm

I am trying to learn Symfony2 and currently : Entity Relationships/Associations (Joining to Related Records) . I have a problem I can not get correct

> Notice: Undefined index: roles 500 Internal Server Error -
>   ContextErrorException

This is the my code:

*Class Role:

```
class Roles
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_roles", type="string", length=225, nullable=false)
     *@Assert\NotBlank(message="le champ nom du role est obligatoire")
     *
     */
    Private $name_role;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $groups
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Groups", mappedBy="roles", cascade={"persist","merge"})
     *@Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $groups;  
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection Permissions $permision
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permissions", inversedBy="roleGroup", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="roles_permissions",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_rolesGR", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_permGR", referencedColumnName="id_per")}
     * )
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $permissions_role;

    /**
     * Roles constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->permissions_role = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

-class permissions:

```
class Permissions {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_per", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom_permisions", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="le choix des permissions sont obligatoire")
 */
private $name_permissions;


/**
 * @var ArrayCollection Roles $roleGroup
 *
 * Inverse Side
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Roles", mappedBy="permissions", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
 *@Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $roleGroup;
```

-Class Groups:

```
class Groups
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_groupes", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 *-- contrainte sur le chmap
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="le champ nom du groupe est obligatoire")
 *
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="string",
 *     message="la valeur {{ value }} n'est pas valide {{ type }}.
 *     Elle est de type chaine des cractéres"
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=5,
 *     max= 50,
 *     minMessage="votre nom du groupe doit comprendre au moins {{ limit }} caractéres",
 *     maxMessage="votre nom du groupe doit comprendre au maximun {{ limit }} caractéres"
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom_groupe", type="string", length=225, nullable=false)
 *@Assert\NotBlank(message="le champ nom du groupe est obligatoire")
 *
 *
 */
 Private $name_groups;

/**
 * @var DateTime()
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime",nullable=false)
 *
 *@Assert\DateTime()
 */
 private $date_create;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Images", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id_images")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $image;
/**
 * @var Roles $role
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Roles", inversedBy="groups", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * })
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $role;
```

-here is my controller

```
class GroupsController extends Controller

{ public function indexAction()
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('GroupsBundle:Groups')->findAll();

    return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
/**
 * Creates a new Groups entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Groups();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('groups_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Groups entity.
 *
 * @param Groups $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Groups $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new GroupsType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('groups_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Groups entity.
 *
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Groups();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Groups entity.
 *
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('GroupsBundle:Groups')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Groups entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Groups entity.
 *
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('GroupsBundle:Groups')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Groups entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Groups entity.
*
* @param Groups $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Groups $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new GroupsType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('groups_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing Groups entity.
 *
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('GroupsBundle:Groups')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Groups entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('groups_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
/**
 * Deletes a Groups entity.
 *
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('GroupsBundle:Groups')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Groups entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('groups'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Groups entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('groups_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

}

the problem:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
>   the type array, object given, called in
>   /home/cros/Desktop/Project_Console/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 555 and defined 500 Internal Server Error -
>   ContextErrorException

*Stack Trace:

in vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php at line 48   -

```
 /*
 * @param array $elements
 */
public function __construct(array $elements = array())
{
    $this->elements = $elements;
}
```

> at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
>   the type array, object given, called in
>   /home/cros/Desktop/Project_Console/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 555 and defined',
>   '/home/Cros/Desktop/Project_Console/vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php',

My GroupsType and RolesType:

```
  class GroupsType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('image',new ImagesType())
                ->add('name_groups', 'text',array('required' => true, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Nom du groupe')))
                ->add('role', new RolesType())
            ;
        }
    }

//My RolesType:
class RolesType extends AbstractType
    {  
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {

            $builder
               ->add('groups', 'entity',array(
                                                'class' => 'GroupsBundle:Roles',
                                                'choice_label' => 'name_role',
                                                /*'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
                                                {
                                                 return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                                                 ->orderBy('r.id', 'ASC');
                                                },*/
                                                 'required' => true,
                                                 'placeholder' => 'Choisir le role du votre groupe'
                                             )
               )

               ->add('permissions_role','entity',array(
                       'class' => 'GroupsBundle:Permissions',
                       'multiple' => true,
                       'expanded' => true,
                       'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                           return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                               ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
                       },
                       'required' => true
                   )
                   )
                // ->add('permissions_role','number')

            ;
```

Thank you

Comment: When does this error occcured ? It seems that you trying to access to a non-existant array key. Can you show us the context of this error ? (a controller maybe ?).

Comment: the problem appears when I completed all fields (name, role, permissions) to create the group. (I changed the subject)  may be the problem here -> mappedBy="roles" !!

Comment: A stack trace would be quite useful here, otherwise it's almost a guessing game

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to dig through all the code you've supplied here, but I'll try to help.

As I see, the `$groups` property in your `Roles` class is annotated with `OneToMany` having `mappedBy` set to `"roles"`.

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $groups
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Groups", mappedBy="roles", cascade={"persist","merge"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $groups;
```

The target entity of the relation is `Groups`, and as far as I see from your listings, this entity does not have a `roles` property, it has `role` instead:

```
/**
 * @var Roles $role
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Roles", inversedBy="groups", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * })
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $role;
```

You should try renaming this property to `roles` instead.

Comment: I tried the solution that you suggested but it appears another problem when adding:: ->Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/syrine01/Desktop/Project_Console/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 555 and defined

Comment: This suggests that one of your forms might be invalid. Try examining the stack trace or tracing the program flow with XDebug to spot the exact place where the exception occurs.

Comment: the problem in constract I do not know why ?

Comment: @Cros well, as I can guess, this could be because you have a form field that maps to a collection field in one of your entities, and this form field returns an single object, while the `ArrayCollection`'s `__construct()` argument is restricted to `array`

Comment: So the problem in the formRolesType in variable "groups", how can I fix it because I am a beginner in Symfony 2 form
thank you

Comment: someone can help me ;(